# Function displaying the number of found products in layered navigation filters in Magento2

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, filter

Which function is responsible for displaying the total count of products in the filters in the layered navigation.

ie) I need to get the count (eg 50 ) in my custom filterable attributes as well.

[image]

This is how I have overridden filter.phtml in my
code
**\Vendor\LayeredNavigation\view\frontend\layout\catalogsearch_result_index.xml**

```
<page layout="3columns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock class="Vendor\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation" before="-" name="catalogsearch.leftnav">
      <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_LayeredNavigation::layer/view.phtml</argument>
      </action>
    </referenceBlock>
    
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\FilterRenderer" name="catalogsearch.navigation.renderer" as="renderer" template="layer/filter.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

**di.xml**

```
<preference for="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\FilterRenderer" type="Vendor\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\FilterRenderer" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to **vendor\magento\module-layered-navigation\view\frontend\templates\layer\filter.phtml**

```
<ol class="items">
    <?php foreach ($filterItems as $filterItem): ?>
        <li class="item">
            <?php if ($filterItem->getCount() > 0): ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $block->escapeUrl($filterItem->getUrl()) ?>">
                    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $filterItem->getLabel() ?>
                    <?php if ($this->helper('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data')->shouldDisplayProductCountOnLayer()): ?>
                        <span class="count"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $filterItem->getCount()?><span class="filter-count-label">
                            <?php if ($filterItem->getCount() == 1):?> <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('item')?><?php else:?> <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('items') ?><?php endif;?></span></span>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </a>
            <?php else:?>
                <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $filterItem->getLabel() ?>
                <?php if ($this->helper('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data')->shouldDisplayProductCountOnLayer()): ?>
                    <span class="count"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $filterItem->getCount()?><span class="filter-count-label">
                        <?php if ($filterItem->getCount() == 1):?><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('item')?><?php else:?><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('items') ?><?php endif;?></span></span>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</ol>
```

Below function will be main `shouldDisplayProductCountOnLayer` & `getCount`

```
<?php if ($this->helper('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data')->shouldDisplayProductCountOnLayer()): ?>
        <span class="count"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $filterItem->getCount()?><span class="filter-count-label">
            <?php if ($filterItem->getCount() == 1):?> <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('item')?><?php else:?> <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('items') ?><?php endif;?></span></span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: do i need to override the filter phtm(Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\FilterRenderer class), as im not making any custom change to it?.. i have overridden only view.phtml for displaying my custom filter(Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation)...but still why are the counts not displaying in custom filters in layered navigation?

Comment: Yup. You have to override in your theme. Try to clear cache, var & check again. It should work

Comment: Could you pls check if my updated answer is correct? i mean is calling the block class rite?  i get Undefined variable: filterItems in Magento cores filter phtml file

Comment: Ofcourse you need to get that Block file as well. Otherwise how will you get Array? So you need to copy `filterItems` related things from Core & Override in ur once

Comment: should i keep the Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\FilterRenderer file in my custom path...if not if i override the FilterRenderer Block, i have to clone the file as is rite? correct me if im wrong

Comment: Yup Clone the file in your theme

Comment: i have cloned the FilterRenderer block class, but still i get Undefined variable: filterItems in my custom phtml

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46970/discussion-between-ankit-shah-and-sachin-s).

Comment: Hi @SachinS Solve?